# Why can I only send one Buffer in node.js

Tags: node.js, buffer

I was just playing around with Buffers in Node and am trying to understand them. I'm not too sure what the reason is for this event:

Here is my code:

```
var test = new Buffer(16);
test.fill(0);
test.write("Hey");
res.send(test.toString());
res.send(test.toString());
```

The message Hey is only sent once. Can you explain this to me?
Also, If the two lines looked like so:

```
res.send(test.toString());
res.send(test);
```

It would say Hey, but not download the second Buffer. Can Buffers only be sent once?
What is the purpose of blocking a second sending? This is probably a dumb question but I am just curious.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Express or something of the sort since `res.send()` is not part of the native HTTP module. Note that `res.send()` (at least in Express) will automatically end the response stream, so if you need to write multiple times, you should use [`res.write()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding).

Comment: yes, I was using express and actually never knew that `res.send()` can only send once. You learn something new everyday. I should've read the docs.